# Configure Angular to ignore the # in URLs?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have some old URLs that I need to support in my application which include a `#` at the start, e.g. `http://localhost:4200/#/result/1234`.

I have the following redirect route set up:

`{ path: 'result/:id', pathMatch: 'full',  redirectTo: 'new-result/:id' }`

which works fine when the URL does not contain a `#`:, e.g. `http://localhost:4200/result/1234`.

But when the URL contains a `#`, the route is not matched and it just redirects to the default route, e.g. `http://localhost:4200/#/result/1234`.

Any ideas on how I can automatically set up my Angular app so that it converts `http://localhost:4200/#/result/1234` to `http://localhost:4200/result/1234` before the route matching takes place?

I am using Angular version 13.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into changing the [location strategy](https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy#description). By default, PathLocationStrategy is used, but can be overriden by injecting another one. Search for `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` and delete it.

Comment: But I don't want to use the HashLocationStrategy. I just want to support old URLs that do use it...

Comment: Can you remove the # before redirecting, or that's not possible?

Comment: To do that, I would have to edit my AWS S3 + Cloudfront config (which is where the app is hosted), and I really don't want to do that and not sure how. I tried to even create a new route called `#result/:id`, but it seems like Angular has does not support routes with a `#` in the name? Any other ideas?

Comment: Subscribe to the router events and see if you can catch it and modify it there.

Comment: Do you have an example on how I can do that? I am really new with Angular :(

Comment: did you try doing in it route guards?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I got it working by subscribing to the router event as you suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by subscriping to the route events in the app component (`app-component.ts`) constructor:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      let url = event.url;
      if (url.includes('/#/result')) {
        let urlSplit = url.split('/');
        this.router.navigate(['result', url.split('/')[3]]);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you try to do it a bit less brittle? You could do something like `this.router.navigate([...url.replace("/#/", "").split("/")])`. This one works for more general cases as well.